# How do I stop SonarQube from assigning issues to the alphabetically "smallest" username?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

When running analyses against our codebase, we've found that with the default assignee unset, sonar picks whichever user has the alphabetically "smallest" login, and assigns any issues it can't figure out to them.

By "smallest", I mean given the user logins [ eblahson, darghson, fvonblehs ], "darghson" would be the "smallest" until someone like "aayron" came along.

I would assume that leaving the default assignee unset would leave the issues unassigned if not able to be resolved to a user, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

This results in whomever is unlucky enough to be at the top of the login list getting a flood of notification emails every time an analysis finishes with modifications.

I've attempted to work around the issue by setting the default assignee to our automated build account, but it'd be nice if this weren't necessary.

Comment: Do you use a SCM plugin like SVN?

Comment: I'm using the git scm plugin. It manages to get things right for the most part, but a large amount of issues still get assigned to the wrong people. My managers are not too happy about that, as it's an incredibly visible issue that undermines the reliability of the whole system.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the plugin, not SonarQube itself. Did you also have a log at the SonarQube log?

Comment: I'll have to do a bunch more investigation into it. Unfortunately, I've worked-around the issue and now have to investigate other instances of Sonar assigning blame to users that had nothing to do with the code; definitely the plugin, but how to detect and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignee is:

- if there's SCM information, the author identified
- else if there's an identified last commiter on the file, this author
- else the default assignee

Here's a link to [official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Automatic+Issue+Assignment).

Comment: Is that process currently documented anywhere?

Comment: I added a link, but information is missing. This is where it may be updated